# Photon, Two master clients

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I've made a room with Photon and that's all good.
I'm the master client.
When I check the 'Photo View' on both players it shows them both as the master client.

As you can see in these images:

[image: The Test account]

Test ^

[image: The master account]

Master ^

As you can see in these two images both of the players are the master controller. Why is this happening?

Comment: Controller, owner, and creater of the object with view id 4002 is [4]'Test', not master.

Comment: @hijinxbassist but in the IsMine on both of the components you can see that after it says if it's mine or not it says (master) both of them have this,

Comment: This is running on the master client right?  This is the master clients copy of the component.  That is why `isMine` is false for the non master client controlled view.  Try launching the server again, but this time have the built version of the game be the master client, and let the editor version be a normal client.  You should see both components say the local client and not master.

Comment: It essentially says who `isMine` is referring to, which is `master`.  IsMine? True (clientAskingTheQuestion)

Comment: @hijinxbassist ah yes that worked, but when i use PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1) it loads 2 of the scenes not one